# Why in the following program Asynchronous function is being Called before Synchronous?

Tags: asynchronous, dart, async-await, dart-pub

```
showAsync() {
  print('Async Function Call!!');    
}

show() async {
  await showAsync();
  print('all done!!');
}

showSync() {
  print('Sync Function Call!');
}

main(List<String> args) {
  show();
  showSync();
}
```

Output:

```
Async Function Call!!
Sync Function Call!
all done!!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `showAsync` function is not doing anything that requires waiting, so it just executes. If you change to the following, the other functions will print first:

```
showAsync() {
  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
    print('Async Function Call!!');
  });
}
```

As Günter pointed out in the comments: "*In Dart 1.x, async functions immediately suspended execution. In Dart 2, instead of immediately suspending, async functions execute synchronously until the first await or return.*" (quote from the Dart docs).

So, if you add a second `await showAsync()`, it will not execute before the sync call.

A detailed explanation is available here: https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/futures

Comment: Right. In Dart 2 sync parts at the beginning of async functions are executed sync.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thanks, I added some information in the answer.